# Select Missing date only if it is Maximum from a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have 2 tables. If table 1 has dates greater than table 2 only those record has should be populated in Output.

Table 1:

```
ID Category Date
1  A        3/2/1990
1  A        3/5/2013
1  C        4/3/1979
2  D        4/3/1970
2  D        5/6/2016
3  E        8/8/2016
```

Table 2:

```
ID Category Date
1   A       3/2/1990
1   C       4/3/1979
1   C       4/3/1982
1   D       4/3/1982
2   D       5/6/2016
```

The expected Output is

```
ID  Category Date
1   A        3/5/2013
3   E        8/8/2016
```

I tried the below query and its giving me incorrect results.

```
select a.id,a.category,a,Date from table1 a where
a.Date > (select Max(b.Date) from table2 b where a.id=b.id and a.category =b.catgory group by b.id,b.category)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/WJRT37911)**

```
WITH cte AS ( 
    SELECT ID, Category, MAX(Date) as mdate
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY ID, Category    
)    
SELECT T1.*  --, T2.*
FROM Table1 as T1
LEFT JOIN cte as T2
  ON T1.ID = T2.ID
 AND T1.Category = T2.Category
WHERE T1.Date > T2.mdate
   OR T2.mdate is NULL
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 AS T1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
     ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.Date > T2.mdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the required output, you need  to use `left outer join`

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM table1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ID
        ,category
        ,MAX(Date) mdate
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY ID
        ,category
    ) T2 ON (
        T1.ID = T2.ID
        AND T1.category = T2.category
        )
WHERE T1.date > nvl(T2.mdate, '01/01/1900');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Filtering Table2**:

```
SELECT ID, Category,MAX(Date) as Date
 FROM Table2
 GROUP BY ID,Category;

| ID | Category |                    Date |
|----|----------|-------------------------|
|  1 |        A | March, 02 1990 00:00:00 |
|  1 |        C | April, 03 1982 00:00:00 |
|  1 |        D | April, 03 1982 00:00:00 |
|  2 |        D |   May, 06 2016 00:00:00 |
```

Now using this to create a **left join** with Table1:

```
    SELECT t1.* 
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT ID, Category,MAX(Date) as Date
     FROM Table2
     GROUP BY ID,Category) AS t2part
   ON t1.ID = t2part.ID
   AND t1.Category = t2part.Category
WHERE t1.Date > t2part.Date;

| ID | Category |                    Date |
|----|----------|-------------------------|
|  1 |        A | March, 05 2013 00:00:00 |
```

Please note that the row with ID=3, category=E wasn't found due to not matching neither ID or Category in the JOIN. 
As good practice if the entities should interact there must be some sort of normalization applied so we could make best use of joins through indexes.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c676e9/23) with your provided data and queries.